# not null constraint failed error even when passing data

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-models, django-views

I am getting NOT NULL constraint error even after passing the data from the form. I am using ajax for posting the data. I checked both the request.POST and network request tab. Both shows the store_contact_number has data in it.

Here is my code

```
class ListStore(FormView):
    form_class = StoreForm
    template_name = 'Store/list-store.html'

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            print('ajax form error', form.errors)
            response = {
                'error': form.errors
            }
            return JsonResponse(response, status=400)
        else:
            return super(ListStore, self).form_invalid(form.errors)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        success_message = "Thank you for listing your store. We Welcome you."
        store, created = Store.objects.get_or_create(merchant=self.request.user)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            response = {
                'result': success_message
            }
            return JsonResponse(response)
        else:
            message.success(self.request, success_message)
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())



class Store(models.Model):
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, null=False)
    token = models.CharField(default=token_generator, max_length=20, unique=True, editable=False)
    name_of_legal_entity = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
    pan_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    registered_office_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name_of_store = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, null=False)
    store_contact_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)


$('.list-store-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // preventing from the brwoser default behavior for form submission
    var form = $(this);
    console.log(form);
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': window.csrf_token
        },

        success: function(data) {
            if (data.form_is_valid) {
                alert('Store Listed');
            }
            // $('.display').html(
            //  "<div class='ui floating message'> <i class='close icon'></i>" + data.result + '</div>'
            // );
        },
```

The error is shown in the store_contact_number as

> IntegrityError at /list/store NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   Store_store.store_contact_number

```
<QueryDict: {'store_contact_number': ['98489678'], 'email': ['admin@gmail.com'], 'registered_office_address': ['Delhi'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['kSaPMgNt'], 'name_of_store': ['BigMart'], 'pan_number': ['98713962'], 'name_of_legal_entity': ['BigMart Pvt Ltd']}>
```

Form

```
class StoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Store
        exclude = ('is_active', 'token', 'merchant',)
```

Comment: Can you include your StoreForm code as well?

Comment: Is it possible that the IntegrityError is coming from your line: `store, created = Store.objects.get_or_create(merchant=self.request.user)`? I haven't used the FormView before, but I think the Store instance won't have been created by that point, so you're trying to create an instance using get_or_create but not passing all the required parameters.

Comment: Deleted my answer, no idea where I got the idea that `merchant` was the problem. Sorry!

Comment: Can you try printing the form to see what you have before validation?

Comment: No need to sorry @The_Cthulhu_Kid . The problem is solved. Thanks to your kind and serving nature

Comment: Glad you got it sorted =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `store = form.save()` at the start of your `form_valid` method and get rid of the line `store, created = Store.objects.get_or_create(merchant=self.request.user)`.

EDIT: Actually it's not that simple because the form.save() will also fail due to not having the `merchant` field specified. You'll need to either need to override either the `__init__` or `save` method of your form so you can pass in the merchant.

Something like:

```
def save(self, merchant, *args, **kwargs):
    commit = kwargs.pop('commit', True)
    kwargs['commit'] = False

    store = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    store.merchant = merchant
    if commit:
        store.save()
    return store
```

then call it using:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    store = form.save(merchant=self.request.user)
    success_message = "Thank you for listing your store. We Welcome you."

    if self.request.is_ajax():
        response = {
            'result': success_message
        }
        return JsonResponse(response)
    else:
        message.success(self.request, success_message)
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
```

Comment: Do I need to specify the exclude the fields 'merchant' from exclude = ('is_active', 'token', 'merchant',)? I am getting an error of ``` save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'merchant' ```

Comment: Have you added the save method I wrote to your StoreForm class?

Comment: sorry my bad. I misplaced the save function. The error is gone. I get 200 status but the data is not saved to database. I checked the commit block by printing just after the if commit: line but nothing gets printed.

Comment: Oh that was my mistake sorry. The line should be `commit = kwargs.pop('commit', True)`. I'll update the answer

Comment: I removed the if commit: block and saved to the database which is now working. But I have one question. Why you have done just super().save(*args, **kwargs)? I thought it should be super(StoreForm, self).save(merchant, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: That's a new feature of Python 3. You can still write it your way if you prefer to be explicit. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/

Comment: Thanks @DBrowne. It solved my problem. Also thanks for the explanation. You told to remove store, created = `Store.objects.get_or_create(merchant=self.request.user)` query. I am not sure when should I use such query and `form.save()`.

Comment: No problem, please mark the answer as correct if it's solved your problem. The general rule is that the form should handle the creation of your object in the database (that's what the django forms are designed to help with). `ModelForm`s come with a default `save` method which uses the validated form data to create the instance for you. This works well in the general case, but we needed to override it to inject the merchant instance. Methods like get_or_create should be reserved for use as part of your 'business logic'.